# New version of Android Eclipse plugin breaks usage on eclipse 3.4 and below

Tags: android

I just noticed that a new version of the Android Development Toolkit was released.

I also noticed that it dropped support for Eclipse version 3.4 which is what I develop on using Pulse to get my plugins.  The update site no longer hosts the older version that did support eclipse 3.4 and below.  This means I can no longer use my older version since the metadata was deleted.

Would it be possible to get an update site that supports the older Android Plugin so I can continue using eclipse 3.4 as mandated by my employer?

Cheers
Ray

Comment: You might just consider updating your Eclipse install (which is what I had to do). Mandating a several year old version of eclipse is inexcusable.

Comment: Okay, now who voted this down? Homeboy is asking for help, and this is not a badly formed question or anything. In any case, my advice would be to convince the employer to upgrade. I'm using the Android plug-in with 3.6 and it works great. What's the reasoning for sticking with 3.4?

Comment: Agreed, gave it a +1 to balance it. Not Ray's fault if his employer won't budge. I had a client not so long ago who flatly refused to move from a 1.3 JRE.

Comment: Thank you ... the request is really not the tough.  My company has standardized on using Pulse to get plugins and Eclipse 3.4 as the IDE.  This choice was several layers above my paygrade and I cannot change that.  Pulse needs real update sites to truly work (so zips would be hard) and the amount of space needed to keep older version around is minimal.  In fact most popular plugins do this for the exact reason of supporting older eclipses.

Comment: While I am able to do work, we will not be able to give this to a new employee or team member.  I would just like to see a single version (you can even state that no new version will be made) on the update site that will support Eclipse 3.4.  (sorry for the multilple comments but I hit the max chars allowed)

Comment: Also @smith324, inexcusable is really harsh.  Eclipse is an IDE and mandating the IDE used must be version 3.4 (which was released in June of 2008) is done at a lot of places.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the older ADT plugins OK, but not the older SDKs. It's not publicised but there are links which work,For example

http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-9.0.0.zip

Versions 10.0.0, 8.0.1, 8.0.0 etc are all available in zip files (just change the URL to the appropriate version number). They're all listed on this page
[ADT Plugin for Eclipse](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html)

Comment: I wonder if there are implications using an older ADT with a newer Android target version though, specifically when dealing with certain XML files.

Comment: I'll bet that you are right. I just think developers should be able to mix and match. For example, I regret updating to the latest tools with the chronically slow emulator, especially as I'm not interested in tablet devices at all.